# Spring configuration to access Openshift elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, elasticsearch, openshift

I'm implementig a page that has a search field and is calling a elasticsearch service using spring.

The connection to the elasticsearch engine was done by using the spring bean provided by spring-elasticsearch (https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch):

```
  <elasticsearch:client id="esClient" esNodes="localhost:9300" />
```

This worked well but I want to move my engine to a different server, so to development and test I created an app in Openshift with elasticsearch using this https://github.com/caruccio/openshift-elasticsearch and change the transported client esNode link. The problem here is always giving me errors like this one (or similar to this one):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.projectx.standard.services.common.SearchEngineService com.projectx.standard.app.controler.common.IndexController.searchEngineService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'searchEngineService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.elasticsearch.client.Client com.projectx.standard.services.common.implementation.ElasticSearchServiceImpl.esClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'esClient': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "//elastic-projectxserver.rhcloud.com/"
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
```

I think the problem is in the link because I'm using the http://... in the esNodes field, but I'm not sure.

Someone know how to put the application to connect to an engine in the openshift?

btw, I found this https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch that looks interesting but I don't know if this will help solve my problem or is worth to change!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This will not work as the https://github.com/dadoonet/spring-elasticsearch code is expecting the configuration in the form of `host:port`. Looking at the exception, you are providing as host as http://elastic-projectxserver.rhcloud.com/. The library will split it by `:` and you will //elastic-projectxserver.rhcloud.com/ as port. This is the reason you are getting NumberFormatException as port should be an int. In your client configuration, try using `elastic-projectxserver.rhcloud.com:80`.

Also, I would recommend you use https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch as that is official Spring ElasticSearch library.

Comment: Thank you about the recomendation. I Already changed my code for the library! About the problem, I tried using the elastic-projectxserver.rhcloud.com:80 but gave me another erro:org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: No node available I'm guessing the link is wrong or the port is wrong. I tried also to use the 9300 port but the same happen!